# mysql-python with MySQL 5.6

Tags: mysql, python, pip

I am having problems installing the **mysql-python** module in my server (CentOS 6.4 x86_64) with MySQL 5.6 installed and Python 2.6.6.

```
[python@localhost ~]$ rpm -qa | grep SQL
MySQL-shared-compat-5.6.12-2.el6.x86_64
MySQL-server-5.6.12-2.el6.x86_64
MySQL-devel-5.6.12-2.el6.x86_64
MySQL-client-5.6.12-2.el6.x86_64
```

And when I try to install the last version of **mysql-python** through pip:

```
[python@localhost ~]$ pip install MySQL-python==1.2.4
```

I get a enormous compilation error which ends in:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 33: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Has someone has installed the **mysql-python** module in this conditions?

I'm attaching the [log file](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/374770/gentuza/pyhon-mysql.log) in case it can help.

Comment: Your goal is to install latest version or stable one?

Comment: My goal is to install the 5.6 version of MySQL because of the full-text search feature.

Comment: I mean MySQL-python, not MySQL :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can fix this UnicodeDecodeError by forcing pip use the default the default localization settings

```
LC_ALL=C pip install MySQL-python
```

Comment: This is a better answer if you're using virtualenv or tox and don't want the MySQL-python installed globally on your system.

Answer (score 1):

Use `yum` to install required package:

```
yum install MySQL-python
```

Also, looks like you've installed mysql from mysql.com, it may break dependencies, because here is how original packages look like:

```
[root@main ~]# yum install mysql-server
Loaded plugins: downloadonly, security, versionlock
Setting up Install Process
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package mysql-server.x86_64 0:5.1.69-1.el6_4 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: mysql = 5.1.69-1.el6_4 for package: mysql-server-5.1.69-1.el6_4.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: perl-DBD-MySQL for package: mysql-server-5.1.69-1.el6_4.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package mysql.x86_64 0:5.1.69-1.el6_4 will be installed
---> Package perl-DBD-MySQL.x86_64 0:4.013-3.el6 will be installed
--> Finished Dependency Resolution

Dependencies Resolved

==================================================================================================================
 Package                       Arch                  Version                         Repository              Size
==================================================================================================================
Installing:
 mysql-server                  x86_64                5.1.69-1.el6_4                  updates                8.7 M
Installing for dependencies:
 mysql                         x86_64                5.1.69-1.el6_4                  updates                907 k
 perl-DBD-MySQL                x86_64                4.013-3.el6                     base                   134 k

Transaction Summary
==================================================================================================================
Install       3 Package(s)

Total download size: 9.7 M
Installed size: 27 M
Is this ok [y/N]:
```

Comment: I installed MySQL version 5.6 because of the InnoDB full-text search feature.Installing the 5.1 version is not an options, but thank you for the quick response! :)

Comment: `yum install MySQL-python` will work anyway - latest available stable version is MySQL-python-1.2.3-0.3.c1.1.el6.